# OpenCL for beginners. What you advise?

Tags: opencl

I want learn a OpenCL for graphics computing, but I newby in the heterogeneous computing.
What you advise? What better for read? 
Please, Could you give me a links to amazon?

Comment: my first advice is to avoid this, OpenCL is not for beginners, also I still have to see a decent SDK for OpenCL with good docs and support for it. OpenCL in theory runs on GPUs, CPUs and any OpenCL-capable device, even modern ARM-based smartphones support OpenCL, in practice, you need a good SDK and really good drivers ( OpenCL is still a driver based technology, just like OpenGL or DirectX, so your program will be as good as the drivers installed in the target machine ) and at the present I see no brand offering both. You will probably achieve better result with some cpu multithreading.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a software, library, off-site resource, or book recommendation site. This is made clear in the [What topics should I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page in the [help]. See the section with the numbered list of items, especially item #5. Good luck.

Comment: Go without SDK, use CLEW and pure OpenCL.

Comment: Use tools that make OpenCL easier. For instance there is clMath and ArrayFire (which I work on). Good luck!

Comment: I realize this is not the place to make recommendations but I remember getting started myself with this just a short time ago, you have to start somewhere so I hope I can save you some time. Do you already know C?  If so, you will find the book by Scarpino, OpenCL in Action, quite accessible. At first all the OpenCL setup seems overwhelming but if you stick with it, its not so bad and becomes second nature. Good luck.

Comment: You can have a look at http://developer.amd.com/india-developer-zone/university-kit-book/

Comment: When I looked into opencl (around two years ago), I read [AMD Guide](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2013/07/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide-rev-2.7.pdf) (because my card is AMD, but its easy to skip the AMD specifics) and also [the spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.0.pdf) ... it's a start if you know C already ...

Answer (score 0):

Starting out in OpenCL I'd recommend

OpenCL Programming Guide - Aaftab Munshi

and perhaps

Heterogeneous Computing with OpenCL: Revised OpenCL 1.2 Edition - Ben Gaster

although I got that one free.